# Linq to XML elements

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I try to read an xml file with LINQ.

The name of the file is:categorizedBooks.xml

and the content of the file looks like this:

```
<category name=".NET">
<books>
<book>CLR via C#</book>
<book>Essential .NET</book>
</books>
</category>
```

The code for reading the file looks like this:

```
  XElement rootss = XElement.Load(@"D:/categorizedBooks.xml");
        XElement dotNetCategoryss = rootss.Element("category");
        XAttribute namehallo = dotNetCategoryss.Attribute("name");
        XElement booksss = dotNetCategoryss.Element("books");
        IEnumerable<XElement> bookElements = booksss.Elements("book");

        Console.WriteLine((string)dotNetCategoryss);
        foreach (XElement bookElement in bookElements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" - " + (string)bookElement);
        }
```

But i get null on this line:

```
 XAttribute namehallo = dotNetCategoryss.Attribute("name");
```

So how to fix this , so that it not will be null?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doc root *is* the category element - try:

```
XAttribute namehallo = rootss.Attribute("name");
Console.WriteLine(namehallo.Value);
```

You'll have to change your other XElement references similarly

Comment: But what will be this element then?   XAttribute booksss = dotNetCategoryss.("books");

Comment: `dotNetCategoryss` is null, because there is no Element named 'category` *underneath* the root element (which itself is named category).  Any reference to a child of `dotNetCategoryss` will throw a Null Pointer exception

Comment: change it to: `XElement booksss = rootss.Element("books");`

Answer (score 0):

instead of *XElement.Load* use *XDocument.Load* or *XDocument.Parse*

```
var xml = @"
<category name='.NET'>
    <books>
        <book>CLR via C#</book>
        <book>Essential .NET</book>
    </books>
</category>";

var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// returns: .NET
var category = document
    .Element("category")
    .Attributes("name")
    .Select(p => p.Value);

// returns: CLR via C#, Essential .NET
var books = document
    .Descendants("book")
    .Select(p => p.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you. ok. But I realy want to have it in a xml file

Comment: So what Black posted works, but how to let it work with this? XAttribute booksss = dotNetCategoryss.("books");

Comment: I mentioned XDocument.Load as it accepts an uri to load xml from file